# Excel VBA code, User form data validation, last instance in a row

Tags: vba, excel

I never had a need to learn VBA since I could always go around it with Excel formulas - not this time.
The game plan - create a user form after inputting data, the data is validated and here the problems started. MInd you I have only studied VBA for 3 days so far.

1. Can't find a solution to find the last value of the cell in a row when there are identical values above. Luckily this time I wet around it but I would like to know how to do it anyway.
2. Can't get my the "user entered data " code to work properly.
   I managed to write a code to check the text boxes but when I add my version of the code to checklist box than it all goes down the drain.

   ```
   Private Sub OK_Click()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   If a1 = "" Or a2 = "" Or a3 = "" Or a4 = "" Or imie = "" Or Surname = "" _
   Or nino = "" Or Post = "" Or sdate = "" Or En = "" Then ' THIS WORKS
      MsgBox ("Please fill all the data DAN, this is not gonna fly!!!")
      Exit Sub
   End If  

   '  Or _
        Or   Or posi.ListIndex <> 0 _ - THIS CREATES AN ERROR MESSAGE every time EVEN IF FILLED ???
   Or Pre.ListIndex <> 0 or  
   Call wpiszdane
   Call FORMULA_FILL
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Unload Me
   ```
3. Next step is to check the data correctness ie. If the code is in the data format, starting date in "data format" etc. - Seems way harder from what-what I googled so far.

What am I doing wrong here? 
Does my First attempt at coding is as hopeless as I think it is?
I believe I may be able to resolve the issue of finding the last duplicate value in a row with a loop as well as check all data in the user form via a loop as well, have no idea how though.
Any help appreciated, thank you.

My file just in case
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14544105192658047753

Comment: also why do you have  'Or Pre.ListIndex <> 0 or' ? the code is going to raise an error there because it is an incomplete statement

Comment: also it is not possible to find a complete solution if you don't provide explicit goals. For example, instead of saying 'Can't find a solution to' you could say "I need to find the value at the last used column of a row of data'

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Starting with the [tour], there are resources to get you started: see the **[help/on-topic]** then if, after [*doing more research*](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), you have a *specific* problem, you can [edit] your post to share your **[mcve]** as well as sample(s) of your data and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips [**here**](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [**here**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/) Plus, here's the [**Formatting FAQ**](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry, I see how i may sound confusing. So yeas, 1. my goal is to find the last value in the row containing many duplicate values. 2. For Pre.listindex - my 1st thought was to add this after "En = "" Then" but when I did I got an error message boxs even when all the form was filled.